# flush/align label and input with each other

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have follow code:

```css
.groups {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups">
  <div class="group">
    <label>Frist given name
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label>Surname
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label>City
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group">
    <label>Text 1
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label>Bla bla bla
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label>My dummy-label
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group">
    <label>Hello, I'm a label
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label>Labelname
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label>Test-label
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to flush labels and inputs with each other (label on the left side of the input with same space) like in this picture:

[image]

How can I do this on a nice, smart way?

Thanks & cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/bq3gjeug/

CSS:

```
.groups {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.group:last-child { margin-right: 0px; }
.group label { display: block; min-width: 100px;  font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 5px; }
.group input { max-width: 100px; float: right;margin-left: 10px;}
```

Comment: This is the solution I searched, thanks. I edited your fiddle and gave 'margin-bottom: 10px' to the label and then it was exactly the alignement I searched. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not work if the width is too small, otherwise it will work.

```css
.groups {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.group:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}
.group > label {
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
.group p {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 110px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups">
  <div class="group">
    <label><p>Frist given name</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label><p>Surname</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>City</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group">
    <label><p>Text 1</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label><p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>My dummy-label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group">
    <label><p>Hello, I'm a label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label><p>Labelname</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>Test-label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer. The only thin here is, that I don't want to have the word-brake on my labels, because than it's not on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.groups {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    width: 118px;
}
label{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups">
  <div class="group">
    <label><p>Frist given name</p> 
      <input type="text">
   </label>
      
    <label><p>Surname</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>City</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group"> 
    <label><p>Text 1</p>
      <input type="text">
   </label>
      
    <label><p>Bla bla bla</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>My dummy-label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group">
    <label><p>Hello, I'm a label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
      
    <label><p>Labelname</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    
    <label><p>Test-label</p>
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```